# Turbo-Drive / Turbo-Stream - Clicking on a link does not update browser address bar / history

Tags: hotwire-rails

My page has turbo-drive and turbo-stream enabled.

When I click on a link, Turbo-Drive makes AJAX call, receives turbo stream template and replaces the dom as intended. However, the address bar on the browser is not being updated.

I have tried these variations without success:

```
<a class="page-link" rel="next" data-turbo-stream href="/page">Page</a>

<a class="page-link" rel="next" data-turbo-action="advance" data-turbo-stream data-turbo="true" href="/page">Page</a>
```

What am I missing?